# operations with REST routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a route for Users controller:

```
  get 'users/get_my_rating'
  get 'users/recover_password'
  get 'users/get_last_comments'
  post 'users/update_rating'

  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'about'
      get 'comments'
      get 'friends'
    end
  end
```

- How to remap `create` REST action to
  `signup` ?
- How to put first 3 rules to the
  `resources :users` block ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate the first 3 routes, do the following:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'about'
    get 'comments'
    get 'friends'
  end
  collection do
    get 'get_my_rating'
    get 'recover_password'
    get 'get_last_comments'
  end
end
```

Also, you can add an :as => 'name_here' to the various member and collection rules to generate the *_url and *_path helpers.  Check out `rake routes` to find the name of the route etc.

To override where the REST create goes:

```
match '/users' => 'users#signup', :as => 'signup', :via => :post
```

Make sure you place this *before* the resources :users stuff since rails tries to find the route from the top down and goes with the first match.

Also, just something to consider: from the name of 'users/get_my_rating' (and the 2 that follow) it sounds like these are more of member methods than collection methods, so I would consider moving these into the member block instead of having them in a collection block.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers about what to do for your second question are perfectly fine, however the best way to remap the `create` action as `signup` is to use the [`:path_names`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) option.

In this case it should be something like:

```
resources :users, :path_names => { :create => "signup" } do
    # All your other routing
end
```

However, one thing to note is that the URL for the `create` action is never shown to the user...the create URL is posted to by the form created by the `new` action.  The URL that the user will see is the one for the `new` action.

As such you might instead want to do:

```
resources :users, :path_names => { :new => "signup" } do
    # All your other routing
end
```

Answer (score 2):

### How to remap create REST action to signup ?

```
match '/signup' => 'users#create', :as => 'signup'
```

giving you

```
signup_url
```

for use in your code

### How to put first 3 rules to the resources :users block ?

not entirely sure what you mean here, but...

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'about'
    get 'comments'
    get 'friends'
  end
  collection do
    get 'get_my_rating' # => UsersController get_my_rating
    get 'recover_password' # => UsersController recover_password
    get 'get_last_comments' # => UsersController get_last_comments
    post 'update_rating' # => UsersController update_rating
  end
end
```

results in

```
 get_my_rating_users     GET    /users/get_my_rating(.:format)              {:action=>"get_my_rating", :controller=>"users"}
 recover_password_users  GET    /users/recover_password(.:format)           {:action=>"recover_password", :controller=>"users"}
 get_last_comments_users GET    /users/get_last_comments(.:format)          {:action=>"get_last_comments", :controller=>"users"}
 update_rating_users     POST   /users/update_rating(.:format)              {:action=>"update_rating", :controller=>"users"}
```